# Getting a 404 when I click my nickname on stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, 404-not-found

I have my account linked with 5 Stack Exchange sites. When I visit [stackexchange.com](http://www.stackexchange.com), I can see my nickname in the header (lobster1234 | log out | chat | meta | about). However, when I click on my nickname, I get a [404](https://stackexchange.com/users/900b10b5-729f-409c-8c10-ead18af12082). Not too big of a deal, but thought of asking it here in case this is impacting more users. Also, this works fine when I click on the nickname on the sites that I've linked with.

Comment: This [link](http://stackexchange.com/users/34a58e76-cfbc-47c0-b299-57d4ef320664) is working fine...

Comment: Indeed, like @mc10 notes: your 404 links to `900b10b5-729f-409c-8c10-ead18af12082` while your actual profile [is at](http://stackexchange.com/users/34a58e76-cfbc-47c0-b299-57d4ef320664) `34a58e76-cfbc-47c0-b299-57d4ef320664`.

Comment: Thanks guys - however, for me it isn't.

Comment: The "network profile" link on your other profile pages links to the correct SE profile. Like [here on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/160900/lobster1234). But it's still a bug that the link in your name is wrong, of course. Did you change anything in your subscription recently? Like maybe you changed from being a cookie-based user to an OpenID user? (I guess not, seeing how long you've been around.)

Comment: Nope, nothing changed. The accounts linked property to my openId account. Thanks so much for looking into this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are still some glitches related to syncing GUIDs across the network. For now, I've updated your stackexchange.com GUID, so the link is fixed for you now.